# How to install Microsoft Outlook 2007 (yes, the old microsoft outlook) with no .pst file

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, pst

how are you?.

I need to totally erase any trace from my computer of my actual outlook.pst file to been able to install microsift outlook 2007 again and then create a new outlook.pst where I will store all my mails, I need to have the .pst file and the microsoft outlook in a pen drive to been able to execute it in any wondows machine without install microsoft oultook 2007 on any machine. This is my goal.

How can I do that?

Update: There are the pictures that shows the problem.

[.pst files attached in the account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K35PI.png)

[.pst file actually configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C2mq.png)

Thanks in advance for the help.

UPDATE 09/11/2021:

After I tried to eliminate de default .pst from the folder where it is stored, outlook shows a message saying that it can't be erased because I need to selecta a new default delivery file.

If I delete the .pst file directly from the folder after unninstalled outlook, then when I install outlook again and after open it for the first time, then outlook asks for the file outlook.pst.

I think some variable remains set even if I use a program like total unninstall to uninstall outlook, I don't know how to solve this last part.

Bellow is the image about this update:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRWi5.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Provide a screenshot of `Account Settings` by editing your question

Comment: Hi @Ramhound, thanks for your comment, question edited to better understanding.

Comment: You have not provided the information I asked for so I am unable to help.  If you cannot provide that information for whatever reason you don't have to notify me of that fact.

Comment: @Ramhound I attached the pictures you asked

Comment: Hit Remove to delete the .PST from the profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarize ***vram's*** solution:

Erasing the profile worked to stop outlook (after installl the program again) to make outlook stop asking for the .pst file.

Comment: Thanks again @Christy for your help.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I noticed that you want to delete the PST file. As far as I know, the screenshot you provided shows the location of the PST file. You can locate that path and delete your PST file.

In addition, I noticed that you want to create a PST file to store your emails. Please refer to this article if you need: [Create an Outlook Data File (.pst) to save your information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-outlook-data-file-pst-to-save-your-information-17a13ca2-df52-48e8-b933-4c84c2aabe7c#ID0EBBF=Office_2007)

Comment: I am writing to see if there is any progress on the issue. If you have any questions or need further help on this, feel free to post back.

Comment: There is the last update about the problem. I tried to erase the .pst file but it keeps saying that I need to add a new default delivery file to allow me erase the actual .pst file. In the update es more information.

Comment: @Ramhound  please see too the comment before this

Comment: Maybe you can try to remove the profile containing the pst file to check if there're any differences.(go to control panel>Mail>show profiles>remove the profile>OK.)

Comment: that option doesn't appear since I unninstalled microsoft outlook, for the last attempt, there will be an option in the registry to erase all related to microsoft outlook 2007?.

Comment: and thanks again for the help

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do mean that you solved the problem through the registry?

Comment: I didn't solve the problem yet but I saw by reading  some other document from microsoft where in the registry are saved the variables for outlook and after checked I didn't find any varaible related to outlook, I used a paid uninstaller that erases all related content (registry included) for any program that I want to uninstall. I will check again to see if is erased and I'll tell you

Comment: I tried again, I mean, I installed again microsoft outlook 2007 and it keeps me asking for the last .pst file used, it means that a variable keeps alive around there and I can't find it no matter what I do

Comment: On the other hand, erasing the profile worked to  stop outlook (after installl the program again) to make outlook stop asking for the .pst file. Please put it as an answer to give you the punctuation.

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem has been solved. I have summarized your solution and written it into a new reply. Would you like to mark the new reply as the answer for other users with similar issue to get reference?